# .net mvc inline code anchor attribute

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, inline, attributes

```
<a href="#" onclick="declineWindow(<%= Html.Encode(item.ConnectionRequestId) %>);">Decline</a>
```

Can anybody explain why the inline code block doesn't work when I use it to populate the value of an attribute? Intellisense stops working and the page throws an error. If I move the block outside a the "a" tag then it works fine.

Comment: what exceptions wa thrown? It isnt anything wrong in popule html attributes in this way.

Answer (score 0):

After another round of debugging I discovered there was a typo in the item member name. I didn't catch it because Intelisense doesn't work when the inline code block is inside an attribute. I am still interested in knowing why Intelisense doesn't work?